# What are Mana Pearls for?

Tags: hack-slash-crawl

In [Hack Slash Crawl](http://www.kongregate.com/games/Void/hack-slash-crawl), you can obtain mana pearls by picking up mana pearls from chests or slain enemies or by selling items.

What are they used for?

Comment: Earning the "Mana Pearls Before Swine Badge" of course!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're basically your score. They're for determining your overall progression for gravestones and for earning certain titles.

Oh, and on some sites with that game you can earn badges/achievements for getting enough. Kongregate is one example.